# Why can't this user delete this file?

Tags: linux, permissions

If I do:

```
ls -al /usr/local/bin/kill-all-sales-apps
```

I see:

```
-r-xr-xr--  1 jenkins root   68 Aug  4 12:10 kill-all-sales-apps
```

If I sudo to root and then su to jenkins, I should be able to delete this, yes?

Other relevant information about the directory and its parent:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root 4096 Aug  4 12:11 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root    root 4096 May  7 17:20 ..
```

If I do:

```
groups jenkins
```

then I see than the user "jenkins" has been added to the "root" group:

```
jenkins : jenkins root run-server-software
```

But if I:

```
 rm /usr/local/bin/kill-all-sales-apps
```

I get:

```
rm: remove write-protected regular file ‘/usr/local/bin/kill-all-sales-apps’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/bin/kill-all-sales-apps’: Permission denied
```

Why is permission denied?

Comment: maybe it is within a directory to which you cannot access?

Comment: If I su to become the user jenkins, and then I start typing "kill-all-sa  " and then I hit the TAB button to autocomplete, the shell correctly autocompletes the command name. That should not be possible, unless the user jenkins has access to the directory where the shell script kill-all-sales-apps lives.

Comment: Sure, jenkins has permission to browse the folder, but does he or she have permission to write to it? The permission to create and delete files follows the directory, not the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to **why** the jenkins user can't delete, the jenkins user needs write permissions on the parent folder of the file you're looking to delete.  This is because you're actually removing directory entries from the parent folder.

> Usually, on most filesystems, deleting a file requires write
>   permission on the parent directory (and execute permission, in order
>   to enter the directory in the first place). (Note that, confusingly
>   for beginners, permissions on the file itself are irrelevant. However,
>   GNU rm asks for confirmation if a write-protected file is to be
>   deleted, unless the -f option is used.)

[Source: Wikipedia - Rm_(Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_(Unix)#Permissions)

So try running...

```
ls -ld /usr/local/bin
```

And make sure the jenkins user has write permissions on /usr/local/bin

Another way to do it is to modify `sudoers` to give jenkins user sudo permissions to rm only that file via sudo.  Here's an example giving the user *joe* the explicit permission to sudo rm the file `/usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt` from a directory he does not have write permissions to.  But limiting him from deleting anything else in that directory.

For example:

```
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# mkdir -p /usr/local/src/noperms
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# chmod -R 455 /usr/local/src/noperms
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# touch /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# echo "hi" >> /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# chmod 455 /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# su - joe
[joe@joeyoung.io ~]$ cat /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
hi
[joe@joeyoung.io ~]$ rm /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
rm: remove write-protected regular file `/usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt'? y
rm: cannot remove `/usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt': Permission denied
[joe@joeyoung.io ~]$ exit
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# visudo
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# diff -Nur /tmp/sudoers.orig /etc/sudoers
--- /tmp/sudoers.orig   2015-08-04 17:17:24.020781442 +0200
+++ /etc/sudoers        2015-08-04 17:24:21.258274163 +0200
@@ -101,6 +101,7 @@
 ##
 ## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
 root            ALL=(ALL)       ALL
+joe        ALL=(root)      NOPASSWD: /bin/rm /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt

 ## Allows members of the 'sys' group to run networking, software,
 ## service management apps and more.
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# su - joe
[joe@joeyoung.io ~]$ sudo /bin/rm /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
[joe@joeyoung.io ~]$ exit
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# ls -al /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt
ls: cannot access /usr/local/src/noperms/hi.txt: No such file or directory
[root@joeyoung.io ~]# ls -al /usr/local/src/noperms/
```

Comment: While you can give jenkins write permission to /usr/local/bin, this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Joshua I agree.  Added an alternative to do it via sudo, but limiting the jenkins user's access to just deleting the one file.